# improve performance for LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This has been a pain on my head for the past few days. I created the database before without any knowledge about the performance of `LIKE`. The query I used is like this,

```
SELECT  ....
FROM    .... JOINS ....
WHERE   tableA.col1 LIKE '%keyword%' OR
        tableB.col2 LIKE '%keyword%' OR
        tableC.col2 LIKE '%keyword%' OR
        .....
```

When I tested the query, it was very fast because there was only around 100-150 records on it. I wanted to search for any string which contains the keyword. As months have past, the database grew huge containing 50,000 records. And this time, I already experiencing the low performance of the query. It was extremely low.

Any suggestions how can I improve it? I can't alter the database because it has already been used by the corporation already.

By the way, my tables were all `INNODB`.

Comment: that's a full table scan... how about an external search engine?

Comment: Maybe your table layout needs to be changed, to avoid such slow queries.

Comment: hi @KarolyHorvath. what do you mean by external search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of search is call [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search), and you really need to use specialized systems for it instead of forcing the database to constantly do table scans. You essnetially hand off all the text you want searched to a search engine, which then indexes it for quick search.

One option would be [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).

Comment: how will it apply on my current scenario? do i have to modify the structure of my database or what? i badly need this :(

Comment: @DerekFloss Np, you would leave your current database alone. Instead, you would install a new piece of software tp handle full text search, like Lucene. You would then need to write some code that imported all of the text you wanted to search into Lucene, and then change your existing code to use Lucene for these searches.

Comment: @Chris do you have full tutorial for this?

Comment: Only what I find with google: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/introduction-to-apache-lucene-for-full.html

Answer (score 1):

Using a wildcard prefix `'%abc'` will very likely stop any indexes being used.

No index = full table scan = (usually) slow...

Btw, 50,000 records is not huge; it is tiny.

Have you considered using MySql's [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)? (requires MyISAM tables)

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables

Comment: fulltext will not support `INNODB`?

Comment: @DerekFloss: no. Currently you there is no transactional engine for MySQL that supports full text search. This will however change with the upcoming version 5.6

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use Full Text Search as other friends mentioned, there's a SQL optimization point that could improve your query:

```
SELECT  ....
FROM    (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE col1 LIKE '%keyword%') A JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE col2 LIKE '%keyword%') B ON ... JOIN
        (SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE col2 LIKE '%keyword%') C ON ...
```

The point is to narrow down your resultsets prior to any join.